# calling a static data member declared in hxx file

Tags: c++, c++17

I have declared a static variable in a file say "example.hxx" and am calling this variable in  the cxx file "example.cxx" in this way
example.hxx file :-

```
class example{
       private:
         static int p;
       public:
         void func();
       };
```

CXX file

```
            #include <example.hxx>
             class example{
                void func(){
                    std::cout<<p;
                }
             }
```

I get an error of undefined reference to p.
Why does this happen and how to solve this ?
I have seen some answers in relation to this question but none deals with separate hxx and cxx files, instead they answer wrt main function. Would be great if someone clears my doubt !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only declared `p`. You need to define it as well, like this, outside the class:

```
// .hpp file
class example{
   private:
     static int p;  // declaration
};

// .cpp file
int example::p = 42;  // definition
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
class example{
   private:
     inline static int p = 42;  // inline definition
};
```

Comment: cigien how can we define "int example::p = 42" in the hxx file ?

Comment: @ShivamKumarSingh The definition needs to be visible where it's used. You should be fine if you define it in the `.cpp` file where you define the `example` member functions.

Comment: you are a life saver, i don't have enough reputations to upvote your answer. I wanted to give 100 upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. First, missing `;` when defining `example` in the .hxx file. Second, you have multiple definitions of the class `example`. Instead, you should define `func` as follows:

```
void example::func(){
    ....
}
```

Third, you have multiple definitions of `func`. Replace `void func(){};` with `void func();`.

After that's done, you're also missing a definition of p. Use

```
class example{
private:
     static inline int p = some_value;
...
```

Or add a definition in the .cxx file.

Comment: "static inline" solved my problems, Thanks !!